# Table Column show the message in center of the row

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I am render the table using json response using html and ajax.

The Json response having three fields.

1. Name 2. phone no 3. No of times logged.

The Json value 3rd column having some values.
sample json

```
var contacts = [{
                "name" : "Bob William",
                "phone_number" : "999912345",
                "no_logged" : 10
            }, {
                "name" : "Harry Roger",
                "phone_number" : "993546466",
                "no_logged" : 9
            }, {
                "name" : "John Rambo",
                "phone_number" : "9945343345",
                "no_logged" : 8
            }, {
                "name" : "Rihana Smith",
                "phone_number" : "9993345673",
                "no_logged" : 7
            }];
```

Screen shot Url : http://postimg.org/image/q2vo1xltj/

Somethimes the json response value(3rd field) is all zero values. That time i need to show some message("None of people logged in our website.Try to improve") in 3rd column center of the table
sample

```
 var contacts = [{
                "name" : "Bob William",
                "phone_number" : "999912345",
                "no_logged" : 0
            }, {
                "name" : "Harry Roger",
                "phone_number" : "993546466",
                "no_logged" : 0
            }, {
                "name" : "John Rambo",
                "phone_number" : "9945343345",
                "no_logged" : 0
            }, {
                "name" : "Rihana Smith",
                "phone_number" : "9993345673",
                "no_logged" : 0
            }];
```

Need to show the message like the screen shot. Can you one help on this.
Screen shot Url : http://postimg.org/image/u9qioe2zd/

html code

```
<table>
    <thead id="table-header">
        <tr class="tablesorter-headerRow">
            <th >User</th>
            <th >Phone No </th>
            <th >No of times logged</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        <tr>
            <td >Bob William</td>
            <td  >999912345</td>
            <td >0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >Harry Roger</td>
            <td  >993546466</td>
            <td >0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >John Rambo</td>
            <td  >9945343345</td>
            <td >0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >Rihana Smith</td>
            <td  >9993345673</td>
            <td >0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >Susian Richards</td>
            <td  >9993456673</td>
            <td >0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Post some code that you've put together.

Comment: Hi, I added html code.please check it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create a div in the table in absolute position with fixed with and then you can also fix the left and top position of the div so that it's in exactly center. Something like

`div{
      position:absolute;
      top:100px;
      left:300px;
      width:60px;
    }`

Remember, set relative position to the table.

Comment: How can i get the response table td width, height and center of table. because every-time the length of data(no of rows) will increase or decrease.

Comment: you can use jquery height() and width() methods to calculate the dimentions and accordingly change the position of the div dynamically.